# Python without if and with if

Tags: python, if-statement

### >What's wrong with this..

```
Code-1

def first_last6(nums):
    if nums[0]==6 or nums[len(nums)-1] == 6:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

---

```
Code-2
def first_last6(nums):
  return (nums[0]==6 or nums[-1]== 6)
```

How come both True?

Comment: Did you mean `nums[len(nums)-1]` in your second code?

Comment: what's the values of `num[0]` and `num[-1]`?

Comment: @RohitJain they are both same.

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary. Oh yes. slipped that .

Comment: Both functions return the same thing because they're both evaluating the same boolean condition and returning it (only the top one does so in a slightly longer way). Perhaps it would be easier for us to help you if you explained what you expect the behaviour of each function to be.

Comment: In code 2 (num[0]==6 or nums[-1]==6)=(True or False)=True

Answer (score 2):

There seem to be two questions inside, so I’ll answer both.

First of all, why are `nums[len(nums)-1]` and `nums[-1]` the same? When specifying an index, Python allows you to use negative numbers that are interpreted like this: if `i` in `nums[i]` is negative, then the index `len(nums)+i` is returned. So, basically, `[-1]` will get the last element, `[-2]` the second to last etc.

The second question is why the two formats are identical:

```
if expression:
    return True
else
    return False
```

and

```
return expression
```

`expression` in this case is an expression that returns a boolean type, so either `True` or `False`. The `if` statements checks exactly that; if the expression equals to true, it will return true, otherwise (if the expression equals to false) it will return false.

So you can (and should, to make it cleaner) just return the expression itself, as it is already true or false.

In the case `expression` itself is not a boolean expression, the if statement will still check to what boolean type it would evaluate (for example a non-empty string would be true, or a number other than 0 would be true too). To keep the short syntax, you can then explicitely convert the expression to a boolean value, using `bool(expression)`, as larsmans mentioned in the comments.

Comment: ... and if it is not already true or false, then `bool(expression)` should be preferred.

Answer (score -1):

uh, because both are exactly the same and they both evaluate to True.

Comment: @TimPietzcker yes, because they are both the same and both are True!

Comment: Tim - the second function will return False if the expression being returned evaluates to False, which will happen in exactly the same circumstances as the top function returning False.

Comment: Uh, yes. Didn't look closely enough. (It wasn't my downvote, in case you're wondering).

Comment: @TimPietzcker Someone upvoted it again, it's okay I just think it's funny :)

Comment: @TimPietzcker Bah, now that you've removed your original comment it looks like mux and I were replying to a non-existent critic! :) I dunno if there's any SO policy on this, but personally I wish people would append an edit to mistaken comments noting that they were in error instead of removing them outright.

Comment: @ all --Thanks 
I recently started python...I know the -ve index for lists but this part..return (nums[0]==6 or nums[-1]== 6) i came across for the first time...without any if...

Comment: @MarkAmery: Unfortunately, editing a comment is only possible for 5 minutes, after that, only removal is possible.

Answer (score -1):

nums[-k] is a shorthand for nums[len(nums)-k]. To get the k-th last element you use the notation nums[-k]. Usually it is clear what the notation stands for and the compiler knows how to turn that python code into machine code, which is why certain language contructs are possible and others are not. Other short hands include nums[:k] to get the first k elements, nums[:-k] to get all elements up to the k-th last element etc. Via google, python docs, you will find much more on this. List operations are a great strength of the python.

http://www.diveintopython.net/native_data_types/lists.html